# Column transform in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I'm new in pyspark.

I want to do some column transforms.

My dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,  8,  9], [ 3,  5,  4], [ 1,  3,  9], [ 1,  5,  3], [ 2,  8, 10], [ 8,  7,  9]],columns=list('ABC'))
```

df:

```
    A   B   C
0   10  8   9
1   3   5   4
2   1   3   9
3   1   5   3
4   2   8   10
5   8   7   9
```

In `df`, each `row` is a triangulation, `columns 'ABC'` are the vertex index of the triangulations.

I want to get the dataframe of all the triangles' edges.

Under conditions:

1. For each edge, always lesser vertex index first.
2. Remove duplicate edges.
3. Edge`[8, 9]` and edge`[9, 8]` are seen as same edge, only remain `[8,9]`. (always lesser vertex index first)

My desire dataframe `edge_df`:

```
1   3
1   5
1   9
2   8
2   10
3   4
3   5
3   9
4   5
7   8
7   9
8   9
8   10
9   10
```

I try to `join 'AB', 'AC', 'BA', 'BC', 'CA', 'CB'`, then `distinct()`, and `drop()` the lesser vertex index on the right column.

Is there any way more effective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case, explode is good. `orderby` is not good, but I added it for the desired output

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df.select(f.explode(f.array(f.array_sort(f.array('A', 'B')), f.array_sort(f.array('B', 'C')), f.array_sort(f.array('C', 'A')))).alias('temp')) \
  .select(f.col('temp')[0].alias('a'), f.col('temp')[1].alias('b')).distinct().orderBy('a', 'b') \
  .show(truncate=False)

+---+---+
|a  |b  |
+---+---+
|1  |3  |
|1  |5  |
|1  |9  |
|2  |8  |
|2  |10 |
|3  |5  |
|3  |9  |
|7  |8  |
|7  |9  |
|8  |9  |
|8  |10 |
|9  |10 |
+---+---+
```